# PostGIS splitting Linestring

Tags: postgis

I have a Street network stored in a Postgis database. All streets are represented by Linestrings. For a further Intersection with a DEM height raster, I would like to split the linestrings in smaller parts.

In a first step, I have segmented all linestring with `ST_DumpSegments()`. Some parts are still too long and I would like to divide them further. Preferably, all segments larger than 10 meters should be split in half (thirds) again. I have already tried `ST_LineInterpolatePoints()` with `ST_splitlines()`, but have not yet found a workable solution.

Comment: Have you found ST_Segmentize https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Segmentize.html?

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/geozelot/postgis-addons/tree/master/SQL#function-set-st_linesubstringsbyvalue-) a [set of functions](https://github.com/geozelot/postgis-addons/blob/master/SQL/st_linesubstringsbyvalue.sql) to extract segments based on maximum segment length or segment count.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I have tried ST_Segmentize() and it works fine. Thanks also for the set of functions. But somehow I can't get them to work. Somehow I get only two rows with the correct length returned. Is there something in particular I need to consider?